# Encrypted .txt file

Tags: php, web, encryption, md5, protected

I have an encrypted file that is correct. But when I try to add to a folder the file appears unconfigured.
What can I do?

Correct Text:

[image]

Wrong Text When I try to upload to a site that serves to decrypt:

[image]

Comment: Show us what you are currently using to do this

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an
 [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the 
 [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks, I forgot.

Comment: You are trying to do 2 conflicting things. 1.) you are trying to reload the current page, but then you are also 2.) trying to change the location to somewhere else.  Which one do you really want to do?

Comment: I have a contact form and I want it when the user clicks the button, if everything is ok, send to the same page but to show the sent message div.
I just tried to redirect the page and it only worked in the chrome and the opera because the firefox and edge do not have automatic refresh. Then I put the refresh code and it works on firefox, chrome and operates but not on the edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```php
echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL='.$location.'">';
```

Comment: This works in Opera and Chrome but doesnt work in Firefox and IE.

Answer (score 0):

PHP (Must work, regardless of browser version / no-script etc.):

```
header("Location: http://example.com/myOtherPage.php");
die();
```

JS (Won't work if user uses no-script or IE. Read more: https://appendto.com/2016/04/javascript-redirect-how-to-redirect-a-web-page-with-javascript/):

```
window.location.href = "https://www.example.com";
```

Comment: I need something to redirect and update and in all browsers.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not working either. The only code that is working for all browsers except for IEdge is what I showed in my question.